# Get index of a table cell relative to the row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some `checkbox` inside the table's cells. I'm binding a click event on each of them. On click, I want to get the index of the current cell relative to the parent row.

For example:

```
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'>....</td>
</tr>
```

I want to get `1` for click event of this `checkbox`.

This is the JavaScript code that I'm using:

```
Grid.tbody.find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
        var dataItem = tablesGrid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
        var i = $(this).index();
        alert(i);
    });
});
```

In this JavaScript code, I want to have the current cell's index, the `I` variable which doesn't work.

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: Please edit your question, and ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` in `$(this).index()` refers checkbox and not the cell `td`.

To get cell index Use,

```
$(this).closest('td').index();  //or $(this).parent().index() if there is no further nesting.
```

---

```
Grid.tbody.find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {        
        var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
        var dataItem = tablesGrid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
        var i = $(this).closest('td').index();
        alert(i);
    });
});
```

Also, I would suggest you use `.change()` event instead of `click()`

To get visible elements index,

```
var $currentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
var  i = $('td:visible',$currentTr).index($(this).closest('td'))
```

Comment: This works for sure. But I have further problem that I'll be thankful if you could help. This table is generated by Kendo Grid, and each row have several none visible cells. So the index I'll get isn't the real index. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the index of the `td`, `$(this).index()` will give you the index of the `checkbox` within its parent(`td`)

```
Grid.tbody.find("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    var dataItem = tablesGrid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
    var i = $(this).closest('td').index();
    alert(i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the index of the column using the parent() call on the target checkbox. If this is what your table looks like.

```js
$("#grid input[type='checkbox']").click(function(e) {
  var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
  var $dataItem = $(this).parent();
  var i = $dataItem.index(); // Gives the column number in any row
  $('#log').append("<p>").text(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
<table id="grid">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check3">
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```